# How to program a Arduino Nano(Bricked) with a working arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano, arduinoisp

I corrupted my bootloader on one arduino, luckily I had a spare lying around. Please help as there is not a single tutorial to help my exact state

Comment: `not a single tutorial to help my exact state` .... yes there are tutorials about using an Arduino as an ISP

Comment: read somewhere to use a capacitor to hold the reset to high state, in some tutorials, not used

Comment: Arduino as ISP and Arduino Bootloaders - https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Answer (score 1):

I have a [page about programming a bootloader](http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) using another Arduino.

Basically you grab the code from [here](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches) and then make up wiring from the good device (which you put the sketch onto) to the device to be programmed, like this:

```
Arduino Nano        Target Nano

D10 (SS)            Reset
D11 (MOSI)          D11
D12 (MISO)          D12
D13 (SCK)           D13

Gnd                 Gnd
+5V                 +5V
```